# When login into 15.10 sometimes my cursor is invisible?

Tags: login, cursor

After turning on my laptop I will login and have no cursor. There will be an Error message telling me Ubuntu has experienced an internal error. However when I hit continue my cursor will reappear. There also appears to be no pattern to when it happens and when it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing gnome
press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to launch terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

Now open tweak tools and choose any different cursor theme..
If it doesn't work please let me know!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Turns out it was a problem with my themes cursors.